# Get frame for a particular text in UILabel with attributed string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm working on a UILabel attributed text for a UI to dispay with three different styles (iOS 12).

I need to find a text frame where can i add a subview beside it, getting the coordinate or actual origin of the provided text would solve my requirement.

Can any one know how to do this?

Comment: you want to display the text in a UILabel with different style and font right?

Comment: I have a text with multiple lines, where one 5 length string should have a background filled with color and that background is a view with custom shape.